# Google Quantum supremacy - how are the 10k years assumed?

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity, processor, quantum-computing, supercomputers

Last week, Google published a paper called [Quantum supremacy using a programmable superconducting processor](https://www.nature.com/articles/s41586-019-1666-5), which brags about:

> Our Sycamore processor takes about 200 seconds to sample one instance of a quantum circuit a million times—our benchmarks currently indicate that the equivalent task for a state-of-the-art classical supercomputer would take approximately **10,000 years**.

How are the 10k years estimated?

Comment: if you don't get a good answer here you might be interested in asking this question on [quantumcomputing.SE](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/). Also, you might want to check out [this blog post by Aaronson](https://www.scottaaronson.com/blog/?p=4372).

Comment: @glS I wasn't aware of that site of SE, thanks (also for the upvote & the blog)!